# How to run C# 8 code from command prompt in windows 10?

Tags: c#, .net

My current version of .Net framework is v4.0.30319 
[Installed .Net framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e33MO.png)

So I tried to download latest .Net framework from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework

But when I try to install this error shows up

[.net framework v4.8 already installed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HrkH.png)

But I can't find v4.8 in the directory.

My current version of C# compiler is 4.8.3752.0 which cannot compile C# 8 code.

[version of C# compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfEXa.png)

Comment: C#8 is supported only for .NET Core 3.x (at least officially)

Comment: All .NET FW versions 4.x are in-place updates and share the same CLR 4 runtime, there is no separate folders for that

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have .Net Core 3.1 installed. Please tell me how to compile C# 8 code using it & without touching Visual Studio 2019.